# Registrar multiplos campos 1 por vez

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

Preciso inserir uma "linha" por vez de uma tabela, como do exemplo da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Irei preencher esse formulário e preciso cadastrar o mesmo no banco. Porém preciso que seja cadastrado uma linha por vez. Por ex: (Segunda, 08:30, 16:30, 30), dps (terça, 08:30, 16:30, 30).

Esse é o meu controller:

```
public string Register(TimeGrid timeGrid)
    {
        {
            if (timeGrid != null)
            {
                using (TimeGridContext contextObj = new TimeGridContext())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        contextObj.workload.Add(timeGrid);
                        contextObj.SaveChanges();
                        return "Registro adicionado com sucesso";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Registro inválido";
            }
        }

    }
```

Model:

```
  public class TimeGrid
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }

    public string NameDayofWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Html:

Entrada
        
        
          Saída
        
        
          Intervalo
        
        
          Total
        
      
       
         
        
      
      
        Domingo

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Segunda-feira</label></div>
     <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="segunda-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.MondayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.MondayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.MondayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Terça-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="terca-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.TuesdayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.TuesdayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.TuesdayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Quarta-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="quarta-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.WednesdayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.WednesdayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.WednesdayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Quinta-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="quinta-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.ThursdayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.ThursdayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.ThursdayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Sexta-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="sexta-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.FridayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.FridayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.FridayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Sábado</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar" ng-click="timeGrid(timeGridForm)">
  </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.timeGrid = function () {
    result = $scope;
    traineeControlService.timeGrid(result.vm)
        .then(function () {

            alert("Teste 1");
        }, function () {
            alert('Erro ao tentar adicionar o livro');
        });
}
```

Service

```
myApp.service("traineeControlService", function ($http) {

this.timeGrid = function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Register",
        data: JSON.stringify(result),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o seu problema?

Comment: Inclua a estrutura da sua classe TimeGrid e a sua View

Comment: Então, alguma ideia?

Comment: o click do salvar faz um post para `Register(TimeGrid timeGrid)` ???

Comment: Sim, o post chega até minha camada controller.

Comment: Inclua action, quero ver os parâmetros que ela está recebendo e tbm o javascript do `ng-click="timeGrid(timeGridForm)`